# How can I delete xml chars from an sql server 2008 table field?

Tags: sql-server, xml, string, pentaho

I am trying to load through pentaho a table into other database.
One of the rows get error due to an xml char hidden between the string of the field.

I do not have acces to pentaho to add a JS step which cleans the xml char, and even I do not know which is the xml char that generates the error.

First I tried to quote the string between `""` expecting that pentaho load the string withouth checking the chars. I can see that in the string exists a strange char in the middle of the last word, but I do not know if in the future it can happen aggain and I want to get better data quality.

How can I detect what is the char that generates conflict and how can I clean that?

Comment: Have you checked if it's a newline char? Those cause problems even inside quoted strings. Also, is there an encoding mismatch maybe?

Comment: @Cyrus the char is: '0x7'

Comment: That is a ["Bell" character](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q815674),which is not valid XML at all. I check with the owner of the source data why and how it got there and if you can expect more such characters.